# How to iterate through a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Server returns a list of data, and I want to iterate through the list.

Here is how the data is structured (got it from browser debugger):

[image]

And the function:

```
function (token) {
    hub.server.getOnlinePlayers(token).done(function (onlinePlayers) {
        MyData.nextOnlinePlayersToken = onlinePlayers.Token;
        $.each(onlinePlayers.Items, function () {
            var id = this.userId;
        });
    });
}
```

until this line everything works fine (`Token` value is null intentionally):

```
MyData.nextOnlinePlayersToken = onlinePlayers.Token;
```

But the next line the debugger shows that `onlinePlayers` is undefined. What possibly is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and [$(selector).each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  // here you can access current li element with this.
});
```

You are trying to get the jQuery object which calls each, but you don't have it. I believe in this case `this` is the global jQuery object.

You need to pass index and value arguments if you are using the `$.each()`

```
$.each(onlinePlayers.Items, function (index, value) {
   var id = value.userId; 
});
```

Comment: in my code I had a typo. `this.userId` should be `this.UserId` .. now it works fine.. thanks anyway